# Pass list of date to batch file in linux

Tags: linux, unix, batch-file

I have a batch script which runs something like this ./test.sh -d 2013-03-25 ; here date is user input;  but what I need to is to pass list of dates to this batch scripts ; i have 25 sequential dates from 03/01/2013 to 03/25/2013 ; how can I pass each date dynamically to this batch executable.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What if a put a range like I say I want to ran between 2013-03-01 & 2013-03-25 , how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to store the dates in an array. This would work well from a shell script.

```
dates=(2013-03-01 2013-03-02 etc...)

for date in "${dates[@]}"; do
    ./test.sh -d "$date"
done
```

Another way would be to store the dates in a text file, one per line. If you did that then you could pass them in like so:

```
xargs -a dates.txt -d '\n' ./test.sh
```

Or, seeing as the dates are sequential and in the same month, you could programmatically loop through them.

```
for day in 00..25; do
    ./test.sh -d "2013-03-$day"
done

for ((day = 1; day <= 25; ++day)); do
    ./test.sh -d "2013-03-$(printf '%02d' "$day")"
done
```

Comment: What if a put a range like I say I want to ran between 2013-03-01 & 2013-03-25 , how can I do that?

Comment: @user1570210 See the last for loop in my edit. That should be easy to adapt.